# Under what conditions the End-compactification is metrizable

Tags: gn.general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a hemicompact space, connected and locally connected. In that case, it seems that it is possible to define a "End-compactification" of $X$ (in the sense of Freudenthal).

Suppose also that $X$ is metrizable. Under what condition on $X$, we will have the End-compactification metrizable ? Is it enough if $X$ is second-countable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the book [Dimension and Extensions](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0873.54037) by Aarts and Nishiura you will find a theorem giving sufficient conditions that the Freudenthal compactification has the same weight as the starting space. Theorem 3.15 and Corollary 3.16 (pages 276/277): if $X$ is rim-compact and the quasi-component space of $X$ is compact then $w(FX)=w(X)$.
In your case, if $X$ is metrizable then it is also locally compact and hence rimcompact, and second-countable too; connectivity says that the quasi-component space consists of one point. Hence $FX$ is second-countable and therefore metrizable.